# Is it possible to see what margins are surrounding my custom view?

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I've built a custom chat bubble and since it draws the text and uses the `DynamicLayout` class, I have to measure the text given beforehand but I'm worried the bounds might go too far because of other items on the left and/or right of it. Is there a countermeasure I could do to prevent this from happening?

Comment: are you using a 9 patch drawable for your bubble?

Comment: what left/right items do you mean?

Comment: Like an ImageView for a profile picture or something

Comment: so your custom view is a compound one (extends ViewGroup)?

Comment: It extends View but like the ImageView would be just to the left, not related to the View

Comment: if it is a View so you should just measure your `DynamicLayout`, nothing more, after all your View knows nothing about its siblings